# Is my consumer RAM RDIMM or UDIMM?

Tags: memory, hardware-selection

I've set out to build a server and I might have ordered the wrong RAM.

The motherboard I'm using is an [ASUS KGPE-D16](http://www.asus.com/Commercial_Server_Workstation/KGPED16/#specifications). In the specifications, it states that I can have 256GB of RDIMM or 64GB of UDIMM. The RAM I bought is consumer, [CORSAIR Vengeance CMZ32GX3M4X1600C10](http://www.corsair.com/us/memory-by-product-family/vengeance/vengeance-32gb-quad-channel-ddr3-memory-kit-cmz32gx3m4x1600c10.html#tab5). The memory format for the RAM is just "DIMM".

The question I have is what type of DIMM is my RAM? RDIMM or UDIMM? Or is it neither, meaning it won't be supported at all?

Comment: The memory you linked to is performance memory (XMP extreme profile, heat spreader, ...). As such is is almost guaranteed to be unbuffered. (Buffered/registered memory is always slower).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- UDIMM = [Un-Buffered RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbuffered_memory)
- RDIMM = [Registered RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory)

Unless you are specifically setting out to by registered RAM, then chances are you've bought Un-Buffered RAM. Un-Buffered RAM makes up the majority of consumer-level RAM available, and registered RAM is typically plastered in warnings it's not for most motherboards.

Comment: So there is no "third type" of RAM just known as DIMM?

Comment: No. DIMMs is just the form factor.  Registered/buffer, unregistered/unbuffered, and fully buffered are different types (which can come in the same form factor).

Comment: @NessDan - DIMM is just a form factor, it means "Dual In-Line Memory Module", as opposed to a SIMM "Symmetrical In-Line Memory Module" (from the 90s). There is also FB-DIMM ("Fully Buffered Inline Memory Module"). Back in the early days of the DIMM you could get away with just calling it a "DIMM", but these days, it's just referred to as a form factor/packaging.

Comment: Thanks guys, so you're for sure that my RAM is UDIMM? (If this is the case, I need to return it right away.)

Comment: A few +1s for good information and for the question. Makes sense to me. Thanks folks.

Comment: Yep, that RAM is definitely UDIMM.